# Get value from another value in a tuple of tuples without using a for loop

Tags: python

Consider the tuple

```
tuple_exp = ((1, 'Raj'),
             (2, 'Robert'),
             (3, 'Kumar'))
```

I have value `"Kumar"` from that value need corresponding value `3`
Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not simply use a dict?

Comment: we can use dict ? but its possible do tuple

Comment: Have you tried `map` @Robert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` can be used to find the position (`index`) of the search element. Once the position has been found then accessing values in it will be compact.

```
index = list(map(lambda i: i[1], tuple_exp)).index('Kumar')
tuple_exp[index][0]
```

Comment: super Rajez,its also great idea

Answer (score 2):

There's a built-in data structure in Python called a `dict`. It maps one value to another

To convert your tuple to such a structure, you can use a *dictionary comprehension* expression:

```
dc = {v: k for k, v in tuple_exp}
```

What's happening here is that the `tuple_exp` is returning one tuple at a time during iteration and that tuple is being unpacked into variables `k` and `v` respectively. Then a dictionary entry is added, where the key is `v` (the second value in the tuple) and the value is `k` (the first value in the tuple).

After that is constructed, you can use the indexing operator `[]` to get the value from the dictionary by key:

```
>>> dc['Kumar']
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok So just for comprehension, a tuple is something you cannot modify (in opposition to a list or a dictionnary). So we have to find another way to do this (I use python 2.7).

Without using a 'for' loop I would do it like this:

1) Instanciate tuple:

```
> tuple_exp= (
(1, 'Raj'),
(2, 'Robert'),
(3, 'Kumar'),
)
```

2) Convert tuple to dictionnary with **dict** conversion :

```
> my_dict = dict(tuple_exp)
```

3) Reverse Keys and Values from dictionnary using **zip**

```
> inv_dict = dict(zip(my_dict.values(), my_dict.keys()))
```

4) Check

```
> inv_dict['Kumar']
> 3
```

Comment: That's very inefficient. Not only it creates two dictionaries, but it also ends up looping over the contents twice

Comment: Yes but at least in contrast to you I did It without a visible 'for' loop which was the question here (if you didnt read carefully). But I didnt say anything because If woulndn't bring anything to the discussion.

Comment: I've read the question. There's no way to do it without a for loop. And you decided to trade one explicit loop for two implicit ones.

Comment: What you are saying brings nothing interesting to the discussion. You are just trying to have the last word, so add as many comments as you want then.. blabla